# Why can't I add properties to a Membership Provider using PowerShell WebAdministration?

Tags: powershell, web-config, web-administration

I have a `web.config` file, I need to add the `SqlMembershipProvider` to it for FBA, and I wanted to do it using the `WebAdministration` module for IIS through PowerShell.

I used the `Add-WebConfiguration` cmdlet and can add the provider correctly but it only takes the `name` and `type` properties and drops the rest. I had `connectionStringName`, `enablePasswordReset`, `passwordFormat`, and others in a hash table that I was passing to the cmdlet but it only took those two out of the hash table and ignored the rest. The same thing happened for my `RoleManager` provider.

I then tried `Add-WebConfigurationProperty` to add `applicationName` to it and got this message:

> "Property applicationName is not found
>   on  add."

When I opened the `web.config` file in Visual Studio 2010 I found that the schema file defining configuration files shows only two properties on membership/add: `name` and `type`.

Where are all the others?

It seems that the `WebAdministration` module is validating the properties added using `Add-WebConfigurationProperty` against the schema file to see if it's a valid property.

The problem is that they are valid properties but aren't defined in the schema, so how do I override this behavior and *"make"* the module add my property that I know is valid??

Comment: Can't you add them directly accessing the XML file ?

Comment: Yes I can add them when editing the file directly.

Comment: So why don't you add them in the file with PowerShell ?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So, you are looking a way to insert data in a correct place in an XLM file? Can you give us the XML file ? or a place where we can download it and the things you want to add into and where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to figure out why the Web Administration module doesn't accept any other parameters. I resorted to using XDocument to manually manipulate the XML file. Oh well, maybe they'll fix it some day...

Comment: Jim have you got any other solution for this?